# What is the functionality(reactive sites) of phenol molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, phenols

My class 12 chemistry textbook says that phenol molecule has three reactive sites or it's functionality is three. But I am confused whether it is so or not, because, what I know, phenol has three double bonds, it must have a functionality of six. Besides, it also has an -OH which is yet another reactive site, so in all making it seven. Please help so that I may have a clear understanding of how to judge functionality of a monomer molecule.

Comment: Could you quote the original text?

Comment: "The functionality of ethene, vinyl chloride and styrene is 2 because these molecules have 2 reactive sites whereas the functionality of glycerol and phenol is three because they have three reactive sites."

Comment: Could you quote the whole section/paragraph?

Comment: "Functionality of a monomer is the number of bonding sites in it. For example, the functionality of ethene, vinyl chloride and styrene is 2 because these molecules have 2 reactive sites whereas the functionality of glycerol and phenol is three because they have three reactive sites."

Comment: Maybe it's talking about [this polymer of phenol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenol_formaldehyde_resin), where indeed phenol only opens the ortho- and the para- sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phenol has $3$ double-bond-equivalent, but not $3$ ***localized*** double bonds:

Look at its resonance structure:

[image]

Courtesy [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phenol_resonance.svg).

Therefore, to a electrophile, there are $3$ reaction sites, which are the *ortho*- and the *para*- positions.

A nuecleophile does not attack phenol.

Comment: Why oxygen atom is not a reaction site?